# Beautifulsoup multiple class selector

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to select all the divs which have BOTH A and B as class attributes.

The following selection

```
soup.findAll('div', class_=['A', 'B'])
```

however selects all the divs which have EITHER A or B in their class attributes. Classes may have many other attributes (C, D, etc) in any order, but I want to select only those ones that have both A and B.

Comment: `soup.findAll('div', class_= 'A B')`, what about the ordering?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham That would work if the class *only* had A and B. For instance `<div class="A B C" />` would not be caught. I'm not sure if that's what OP wants or not. It sounds like he wants to catch them, even if they have many other classes.

Comment: @sytech this is precisely the case.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use `css selectors` instead:

```
soup.select('div.A.B')
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use CSS selectors instead, which is probably the best solution here.

```
soup.select("div.classname1.classname2")
```

You could also [use a function](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function).

```
def interesting_tags(tag):
    if tag.name == "div":
        classes = tag.get("class", [])
        return "A" in classes and "B" in classes

soup.find_all(interesting_tags)
```

Comment: Great solution and it works well for my purposes. How does the last line execute without a `tag` input within `interesting_tags()`?

Comment: @InfiniteFlashChess The `find_all` method (as well as `find`) accepts a callable. Inside the `find_all` method, BeautifulSoup will call the provided callable, passing it in the tag argument for every tag. If your callable returns `True`, the tag will be included in the result set. [relevant docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function)

Answer (score 6):

```
table = soup.find_all("tr",class_=["odd","even"])
```

Try this way! Make sure you are using proper structure of those quotes and braces. It confused me.

Comment: This will find elements that match one or more of the class names in the list. The CSS selector approach is much better.

Answer (score 1):

**1**
some tag like:

```
<span class="A B C D">XXXX</span>
```

if you want to use CSS selector to get the tag, you can write the code for the class attribute as following:

```
spans = beautifulsoup.select('span.A.B.C.D')
```

**2** And if you want to use this for id attribute, you change as following:

```
<span id="A">XXXX</span>
```

change the symbol you use in select function:

```
span = beautifulsoup.select('span#A')
```

What we learn is that its grammer is like the CSS3

Answer (score 1):

for latest `BeautifulSoup`, you can use [regex](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/index.html#a-regular-expression) to search `class`

code:

```py
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

multipleClassHtml = """
<div class="A B">only A and B</div>
<div class="A     B">class contain space</div>
<div class="A B C D">except A and B contain other class</div>
<div class="A C D">only A</div>
<div class="B D">only B</div>
<div class=" D E F">no A B</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(multipleClassHtml, 'html.parser')

bothABClassP = re.compile("A\s+B", re.I)
foundAllAB = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class": bothABClassP})
print("foundAllAB=%s" % foundAllAB)
```

output:

```sh
foundAllAB=[<div class="A B">only A and B</div>, <div class="A    B">class contain space</div>, <div class="A B C D">except A and B contain other class</div>]
```

[image: vscode debug bs4]