# Data Scraping across <div>'s

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract information from a repeating set of rows containing many embedded 's.  For the page, I am trying to write a scraper to get various elements from [this](https://www.firstinspires.org/team-event-search#type=teams&sort=name&keyword=NJ&programs=FLLJR,FLL,FTC,FRC&year=2017) page.  For some reason, I can't find a way to get to the  tag with the class that contains the information for each row.  Further, I am not able to isolate the sections that I will need to extract the information. For reference, here is a sample of one row:

```
<div id="dTeamEventResults" class="col-md-12 team-event-results"><div>
    <div class="row team-event-result team-result">
        <div class="col-md-12 main-info">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-7 event-name">
                    <dl>
                        <dt>Team Number:</dt> 
                        <dd><a href="/team-event-search/team?program=JFLL&amp;year=2017&amp;number=11733" class="result-name">11733</a></dd>
                        <dt>Team:</dt> 
                        <dd> Aqua Duckies</dd>
                        <dt>Program:</dt> 
                        <dd>FIRST LEGO League Jr.</dd>
                    </dl>
                </div>
```

The script I have started to build looks like the following:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.firstinspires.org/team-event-search#type=teams&sort=name&keyword=NJ&programs=FLLJR,FLL,FTC,FRC&year=2017'

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

rows = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class":"row team-event-result team-result"})
```

whenever I run len(rows), it always results in 0. I seem to have hit a wall and am having trouble. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content of this page is generated dynamically so to catch that you need to use any browser simulator like `selenium`. Here is the script which will fetch your desired content. Give this a shot:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium  import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.firstinspires.org/team-event-search#type=teams&sort=name&keyword=NJ&programs=FLLJR,FLL,FTC,FRC&year=2017')
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")
for items in soup.select('.main-info'):
    docs = ' '.join([' '.join([item.text,' '.join(val.text.split())]) for item,val in zip(items.select(".event-name dt"),items.select(".event-name dd"))])
    location = ' '.join([' '.join(item.text.split()) for item in items.select(".event-location-type address")])
    print("Event_Info: {}\nEvent_Location: {}\n".format(docs,location))
driver.quit()
```

The results look something like:

```
Event_Info: Team Number: 11733 Team: Aqua Duckies Program: FIRST LEGO League Jr.
Event_Location: Sparta, NJ 07871 USA

Event_Info: Team Number: 4281 Team: Bulldogs Program: FIRST Robotics Competition
Event_Location: Somerset, NJ 08873 USA
```

Comment: Yea I figured it was dynamically generated.  turns out I hadn't made it to that chapter yet, apparently!  Still brushing up on my skills.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This seems like an issue of multiple-class tags. I believe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40305678/beautifulsoup-multiple-class-selector) might help you figure out the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can search specifically for `dt` and `dd`, the tags containing the target data:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib2 import urlopen as uReq
import re
data = str(uReq('https://www.firstinspires.org/team-event-search#type=teams&sort=name&keyword=NJ&programs=FLLJR,FLL,FTC,FRC&year=2017').read())
s = soup(data, 'lxml')
headers = map(lambda x:x[:-1], [[b.text for b in i.find_all('dt')] for i in s.find_all('dl')][0])
data = [[re.sub('\s{2,}', '', b.text) for b in i.find_all('dd')] for i in s.find_all('dl')]
print(data)
final_data = [dict(zip(headers, i)) for i in data]
print(final_data)
```

When running this code on your example above, the output is:

```
[[u'11733', u' Aqua Duckies', u'FIRST LEGO League Jr.']]
[{u'Program': u'FIRST LEGO League Jr.', u'Team Number': u'11733', u'Team': u' Aqua Duckies'}]
```

Comment: @JohnFalconi glad to help!