# i need to retrieve data from a class tag without data in inner tags using beautifulsoup python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i need to retrieve data from *"ikman.lk"* using **beautifulsoup** python library.

```
 <span class="t-small summary-count">  Showing 1-25 of 131 ads for <span>"Samsung Galaxy A5"</span>.</span>
```

I need to get only the "Showing 1-25 of 131 ads" part using Beautifulsoup library.
I tried,

```
    pgn = soup1.find("span", {"class": "t-small summary-count"}).text
    print(pgn)
```

but it says"'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' ".
Thank

Comment: And what is your exact question? I would assume that `find` does not work for multiple classes

Comment: I need to get only the text part which is ("Showing 1-25 of 131 ads"). if you have a way please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Beautifulsoup multiple class selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40305678/beautifulsoup-multiple-class-selector)

Comment: sorry mate, it's not the problem in multiple class. in my code <span> tag only have one class. but the problem is i need to extract only the text part. is there a way to retrieve only the text inside first <span>  tag.

Comment: Are you sure about "one class"? You've given the two distinct classes `t-small` and `summary-count` in your example - a class name must not contain a space

Answer (score 1):

If i get the question correctly, you need to get the initial text from a tag just before the child tag. A tag’s children are available in a list called [.contents](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children) .

You can use `.contents[0]`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html="""
<span class="t-small summary-count">  Showing 1-25 of 131 ads for <span>"Samsung Galaxy A5"</span>.</span>
"""
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
pgn = soup.find("span", {"class": "t-small summary-count"})
print(pgn.contents)
print(pgn.contents[0])
```

Output

```
['  Showing 1-25 of 131 ads for ', <span>"Samsung Galaxy A5"</span>, '.']
  Showing 1-25 of 131 ads for
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to find `<span> .... </span>` with `select` and then get text before it with using `previousSibling`
All code :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = ''' <span class="t-small summary-count">  Showing 1-25 of 131 ads for 
<span>"Samsung Galaxy A5"</span>.</span>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
get_span = soup.find('span' , attrs={'class' : 't-small summary-count'})



for a in get_span.select('span'):
    print a.previousSibling
```